# Google Trends embed_loader URL

Tags: javascript, embed, google-trends

We have an app that embeds a Google Trend chart. However every couple of months the chart stops working. Each time it seems that the embed JS version has been incremented and the old version is no longer available.

This was today's fix:

```
-<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/760_RC01/embed_loader.js"></script>
+<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/962_RC10/embed_loader.js"></script>
```

Is there any kind of URL that 301's to the latest version? I've tried:

```
https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/latest/embed_loader.js
```

... but it doesn't work.

Surely this approach from Google means any page on the internet with an embedded script will eventually break?!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the script as backend

```
wp_enqueue_script('google-trends-js-chart', 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/trends_nrtr/3349_RC01/embed_loader.js', [], null, true);
    
//localize script
wp_localize_script('google-trends-js-2', 'codedeyoGoogleTrends', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('codedeyo-google-trends-nonce'),
        'plugin_dir_url' => plugin_dir_url(CODEDEYO_TRENDS_PLGUN_FILE),
        'default_country' => get_option('codedeyo_google_trends_default_country', 'US')
    ));
```